# I need to model my Javascript application

Tags: modeling

Hy,

I was looking for a software to model an application, because is becoming too big.
Like this:

Class - A
Methods - a, b, c, d, e

Class - B
Methods - a, b, c, d, e

This should be in graphical mode, Classes are some boxes, and the methods are in the box.
Then I would like to be able to make a arrow from one method to another.

Do you know some good software?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick google search for Javascript and UML 
and found this: http://jsuml.org/

there is also: http://www.filesland.com/software/javascript-13.html

Comment: This should not be only focused on javscript. I want to be something generic... Only to structure the application, see the workflow.

Comment: The way I read your question, I thought you had a code library and needed to create UML from code..  If that is the case, you'll need a tool that can parse whatever language your library is in.  There are many tools that can parse a variety of languages, the better ones will cost some money.
However, if you need to design your application first in UML, then there are a ton of free ones out there.  Google is our friend, run some searches.

Comment: I want to write the code on my own. But what I need is not exactly UML, because I can't link methods, but only classes...